# Copying stdin to buffer

Tags: c, tcp, stdin

Working on a networking project and using select() and FD_ISSET to watch stdin and also TCP connections simultaneously. I can't seem to capture keyboard entry in a buffer so that I can process it. Here's what I have:

```
if (FD_ISSET(0, &read_set)) {

    fprintf(stdout, "Keyboard input noted:\n");

    size_t bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFSIZE, stdin);
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), bytes, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (bytes < BUFFSIZE)
        if (feof(stdin))
            break;

    fprintf(stdout, "buffer: %s\n", buffer);
}
```

The first printf statement outputs as soon as I hit the enter key, but the second one never fires. Can someone tell me what I am missing? Thanks!

EDIT: When I change `size_t bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFSIZE, stdin);` to something like

```
size_t bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 2*sizeof(char), stdin);
```

and then type in something like `aa<enter>` I can force it to output, but this is way too small. I need a way to get it return from fread when the enter key is read.

Comment: Try writing `bytes` to stderr.

Comment: Are you hitting the `break`?

Comment: @woolstar I changed the fwrite line to `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char, ytes, stderr);` - still no output

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey I added an output line right before the `break`. It doesn't appear that I am getting here.

Comment: Print `bytes`: `fprintf(stderr, "bytes read = %zu", bytes);`. If the answer is 0, you know why you don't see anything.

Comment: Well, I put that line both immediately after the `fread` line and also as the last line in the block. Never fires. Looks like I'm not returning from the `fread` call. How do I get this to terminate when I'm not reading the full BUFFSIZE number of characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the `fread` line to

```
size_t bytes = read(0, buffer, BUFFSIZE)
```

and that gets past the problem of `fread` not returning. Unfortunately, this also seems to pick up the carriage return character, which gives me an extra byte at the end of my buffer that I need to remove. For example, if I type in 'aa' and then output `bytes`, it shows 3 not 2. Now I need to figure out how to solve that problem.

Any better answers are very welcome. Thanks to all.

Comment: Almost all forms of the `fread` and `read` give you the newline.  Just a matter of trimming the end of the buffer.  Something like `buffer[bytes--]= '\0'`